# Angular4 Internationalization fails

Tags: angular, internationalization

I have created a new angular app and created the localization files as suggested in the https://angular.io/guide/i18n.

But when I do ng serve --aot --i18nFile=src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --locale=fr --i18n-format=xlf I am getting the below error.

ERROR in Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Projects\Angular-cli\src\locale\messages.fr.xlf'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:642:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:510:33)
    at Function.CodeGenerator.create (C:\Projects\Angular-cli Clarion Web\ClarionWebApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:63:33)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.codeGen (C:\Projects\Angular-cli Clarion Web\ClarionWebApp\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.j
s:72:53)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then (C:\Projects\Angular-cli Clarion Web\ClarionWebApp\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:391:44)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

But the file messages.fr.xlf do exists.

Comment: run `dir C:\Projects\Angular-cli\src\locale` and post the output.

Comment: It says "The system cannot find the path specified". The actually path is C:\Projects\Angular-cli <<proj name>> \src\locale. I removed the proj name while posting the questions. There is space in between Angular-cli and Proj name, does it created any issue?

Comment: Try without the space, and you'll know. Spaces in files and folders always end up causing trouble. I'd avoid them.

Comment: I removed the space and tried again, I got the same error. But this time when I did dir "path" I am getting as below...... Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 6411-D474

 Directory of C:\Projects\Angular-cliProjname\Projname\src\locale

11/27/2017  03:10 PM    <DIR>          .
11/27/2017  03:10 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/27/2017  03:10 PM             1,253 messages.fr..xlf
11/27/2017  03:21 PM             1,217 messages.xlf
               2 File(s)          2,470 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  115,683,516,416 bytes free

Comment: So, just read. Your file is named `messages.fr..xlf`, not `messages.fr.xlf`.

Comment: I found the issue. There is an extra . in messages.fr..xlf